# Smoothing HX711 arduino library readings

Tags: arduino

I am making a 50kg weighing scale using HX711 ADC. My project includes Atmega328 along with 74HC595 for driving 5 7segment displays(multiplexed). I am using the function `scale.get_units()`to fetch the data and the values are very well displayed on the 7segments. The problem I am facing is the readings on the 5th digit (right most 1's) are unstable. Now, if I use `scale.read_average(5)`, my display scanning gets slow. I was wondering if there is a way to average the readings in a loop like the conventional way. I tried it but with no luck! It keeps showing random added numbers. Any help would be highly appriciated. Below is the code inside the loop. Let me know if full code is needed. Thanx in advance!!

```
if (scale.is_ready()){
 weight = scale.get_units();
 finalWeight = weight * 1000;
 }
 
 for(int i=0; i<10 ;i++){
 sum += finalWeight;
 average = sum/10;
 }

  if(average<0){
  break_number(0);
   }
    else{
    break_number(average);
    }
      display_number();
      delay(1);
```